# Use route parameters with `app.use` on Express

Tags: express, routeparams

I cannot use route parameters with `app.use` on Express 4.16.2.

I have a statement like this:

```
app.use('/course-sessions/:courseSessionId/chapter-sessions', chapterSessionsRouter)
```

And, in chapter sessions router:

```
// Index.
router.get('/', ...resource.indexMethods)
```

When I got `'/course-sessions/0/chapter-sessions/'`, I have 404.

Then I am trying a statement like this:

```
app.get('/course-sessions/:courseSessionId/chapter-sessions', ...chapterSessionResource.indexMethods)
```

Now I have the result I want. So route parameters don't work with `app.use`.

While I am researching, I got [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/696) and [this pull request](https://github.com/expressjs/express/pull/1935) which closes the issue. But it seems that the issue is still around here. Or do I make something wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to setup your router in a different way, try using `mergeParams` to access parameters in parent routes.

```
let router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
```

See docs: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: Thanks, it worked! It worked with both `app.use` and `router.use`.

Answer (score 2):

I’d do only app.use('/course-sessions/', chapterSessionsRouter) and handle the id inside the router.

Comment: I think this is the most appropriate solution for now. But it would be good if `app.use` supports route parameters, or `router.use` supports a router as a middleware...